# Can't get Signal / Slot to work

Tags: php, typo3, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

After a Youtube ID was saved, I'd like to get some API data and write it into the database. But my function never gets called. What I've tried so far:

ext_localconf.php

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\SignalSlot\\Dispatcher')->connect(
    'TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Persistence\\Generic\\Backend',
    'afterInsertObject',
    'VENDOR\\MyExtension\\Slots\\SaveVideo',
    'getVideoData'
);
```

Classes/Slots/SaveVideo.php

```
namespace VENDOR\MyExtension\Slots;

class SaveVideo {
    public function getVideoData($object) {     
        echo "Yeaha";
        var_dump($object);
    }
}
```

Comment: How is the Youtube ID saved? Through a Frontend plugin or the Backend/TCA?

Comment: It is saved through the Backend/TCA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you edit records in the backend then you do it through TCE (TYPO3 Core Engine) also known under the names TCEForm and TCEMain.

#### TCEForm

TCEForm generates a form from the TCA (Table Configuration Array) where you can edit and create new records.

#### TCEMain

TCEMain takes care of processing the data and store it in the database. It also takes care of commands like move, copy, delete, undelete, localize and version. TCEMain has a new name, `DataHandler`. The `DataHandler` class can be found here:

`typo3/sysext/core/Classes/DataHandling/DataHandler.php`

[You can read more about TCE here](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/Typo3CoreEngine/Index.html)

#### How to implement the hook

The `DataHandler` class has a lot of hooks where you can manipulate the data before it is stored in the backend. Try searching for `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']` and you will find something like below.

```
if (is_array($GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['t3lib/class.t3lib_tcemain.php']['processDatamapClass'])) {
```

We can use this to registre oure hook in `ext_localconf.php`. Be aware that there are many hooks types available but it is the `processDatamapClass` we are interested in.

In you `ext_localconf.php` add:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['t3lib/class.t3lib_tcemain.php']['processDatamapClass'][] = 'VendorName\\ExtentionName\\Hooks\\ProcessDatamapClass';
```

Create the file `extension_name/Classes/Hooks/ProcessDatamapClass.php` and at this content.

```
<?php
namespace VendorName\ExtentionName\Hooks;

class ProcessDatamapClass {
    public function processDatamap_postProcessFieldArray($status, $table, $id, &$fieldArray, $obj) {
        if($table == 'tx_extentionname_domain_model_yourtable') {
            // Your code goes here!
            // Note that $fieldArray is a reference so you can now modify the fields
            // before they are stored in the database
        }
    }
}
```

This code will now run every time you edit or creates a record in the backend. Therefore it is important to encapsulate your code for your record type / table name only!

I hope this helped you. [You can read more about hooks here](https://typo3.org/documentation/article/how-to-use-existing-hooks-in-your-own-extension/).